# How can I merge the different elements of the list?

Tags: r

I have a list/dataframe such as

```
a b c d e f g VALUE   
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 934
```

what I wanted to do is to print,

`1010001` without using for loop. so basically, take those integers as a string and merge them while printing?

Comment: You want to do that for every row or just for one row? Or your data frame only has one row beyond the titles? Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: if it is a dataframe then `do.call(paste0, dat)` should do it. If not, can you update your question with the results of `dput(head(dat))` please

Comment: In this simple case, you dont need a loop: `paste(dataframe[1,1:7],collapse="")` 
Where dataframe is your dataframe name

Comment: I have to say the immediate downvote seems a bit overzealous ; the op did provide a sample (which could be improved) and expected outcome.

Comment: it was my first time asking a question. I will improve my self on later ones. sorry for my bad england

Comment: Hi Tunc, the language in your question is fine. The question would just benefit from displaying your data in a way that it is obvious to others (us) what type of R object it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example is worth a wee read. cheers

Comment: what is the `class()` of that object?

Answer (score 0):

I will define a function, which truncate the last value and paste all the other elements together. And then use "apply" on all the dataframe

```
cc <- data.frame(a=1,b=0,c=1,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=1,VALUE=934)

# This function contains the all the jobs you want to do for the row.
myfuns <- function(x, collapse=""){
  x <- x[-length(x)] # truncate the last element
  paste(x,collapse="") # paste all the integers together
}

# the second argument "MARGIN=1" means apply this function on the row 
apply(cc,MARGIN=1,myfuns2)   # output: "1010001"
```

Comment: OP wanted to do this without using a `for` loop. Your suggestion will be probably even worse. This can be both easily and efficiently solved by just  `do.call(paste, c(sep = "", cc[-length(cc)]))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks very much for the suggestion. I don't know, what actually happened in `apply`. Do you means, the apply use the `for` loop internal?

Comment: xirururu,  yes apply uses a for loop, in r code ... type `apply` into the console to see the function code